# SQL: CUSTOMER that has bought a WORK from every ARTIST || 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, relational-division

So I have 2 tables that both contain IDs

work:

```
workID, artistID
1       6
2       7
3       8
4       6
5       6
```

trans:

```
CustomerID, workID
10          1 
11          2
12          3
10          4
10          5
```

So far I've only managed to put all the ID's together but the result I need is to show any customerID that has purchased a workID from every artistID:

```
SELECT
     trans.customerID, trans.workID, work.artistID
FROM
    trans
      INNER JOIN work
      ON trans.workID=work.workID
WHERE
    trans.customerID IS NOT null
ORDER BY
    trans.customerID;
```

Basically I have no idea what my next step should be, if anyone could point me in the right direction or explain a solution that would be great.

EDIT: added simplified data to tables

Comment: Hmmm, I think you should decide on the database you are using.  This is tagged for three databases, but I bet you are only using one.

Comment: tagged for 3? no idea how that happened. Yes it is 1 database.

Comment: ok yeah I saw what I did my bad, Oracle-sqldeveloper.

Comment: This homework question asks you to implement [relational division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29). Why did you not know this term?

Comment: How do you find the list of "every artist" here? Is there any Artist's master table? Or do you mean that the distinct of artistids from work table will suffice the count? I bet there must be a Artist master table that will hold the list of all available artists, better to involve that table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
SELECT t.customerId 
FROM 
  ( SELECT t.CustomerId, COUNT(DISTINCT artistId) as artists
    FROM trans t INNER JOIN work w ON w.workid = t.workid) t 
  INNER JOIN 
  ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT artistId) artists FROM work) a ON  t.artists = a.artists
```